# Ignoring the first character while using getline function for inputs in c++

Tags: c++

Why taking input using getline in c++ program is automatically ignoring first letter of my input?
What should i do to solve this problem?

edit 1: I have used getline in other functions of same program along with cin.ignore() but it is working fine there.

```
    cout<<"Enter the roll no: ";        
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,rollno);
    cout<<"Enter the name of book you want to issue:";  
    cin.ignore();                                       
    getline(cin,input);                 //input= think and row rich
    cout<<"What's the return data";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,input_date);           // input=20-8-2019

    cout<<input<<" "<<input_date<<endl;      //output of inputs = hink and grow rich and 0-8-2019
```

If i try to take input without cin.ignore() program is not taking any input..

Comment: You are telling it to with `cin.ignore();` It should work without `cin.ignore();` Is this a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you know what `cin.ignore()` does and when to use it?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp . Without cin.ignore() we can't use getline function for strings.It will take input 1st time and then will not ask for input 2nd and 3rd time.

Comment: @BilalKhan That is false. Why would you think that? When you say the program "is not taking any input", what precisely do you mean? What exactly goes wrong? (I suspect you've been sprinkling `cin.ignore()` around your code to make it work without understanding where you need it and why so, as here, you have it where it makes no sense.) Hint: Only use it when you specifically need to ignore something.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz , I have already tried without cin.ignore() and it is not working correctly..  ``` Enter the roll no: Enter the name of book you want to issue: ``` I have executed the code again and here it is not asking me for roll no!!!

Comment: WIthout using cin.ignore() it is not asking me for roll no and asking directly for name of book

Comment: @BilalKhan You might be sending more than one newline when you hit enter.

Comment: What should i do to solve the problem? @LarryB

Comment: @BilalKhan Because your code is in an illogical order, it's hard for you to see what is doing what. The first `cin.ignore` in the code you showed us is probably required by previous code that you haven't shown us. The others, part of the code you did show us, need to be removed. Do you understand when to use `cin.ignore`? Can you explain precisely what each call to `cin.ignore` is ignoring?

Comment: @BilalKhan, I tried the code you included **without** the `cin.ignore` statements and it works fine for me. You'll have to debug your program and figure out what is going on and why.

Perhaps changing your code to read one character at a time from the stream to see what's there as David suggests.

Comment: The general rule of thumb for `ignore` is use it AFTER the operation that left data you need ignored in the stream. If you use it BEFORE another operation, sooner or later you will invoke the other operation without unwanted data in the stream.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    cout<<"Enter the roll no: ";
    istream& ignore (streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF);  //by using this line my code starts working properly.
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,rollno);
    cout<<"Enter the name of book you want to issue:";
    getline(cin,input);
    cout<<"What's the return data";
    getline(cin,input_date);
```

The above code is now taking input of rollno,book name and date one by one and not ignoring any character.Thanks everyone for help

Comment: All `istream& ignore (streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF);` does is declare a function that's not used in the sample given in the question. If this has a runtime effect, you have an error elsewhere in the code that is somehow exposed by not declaring this function.